# Around the Clock

Tags: graphics, date-and-time

I want to produce with Mathematica something like this

[image]

Or this

[image]

12 hours should be arranged in a pleasing ("rotated") style around / within a rectangle. I don't ask for the hands - depending on numerical input - but only for a `Graphics` to begin with.

- "Have you tried anything ?"
- "Sure, but with non-presentable results."

Comment: You're late http://stackoverflow.com/q/8187378/353410

Comment: @belisarius But my question concerns "rectangular clocks", not the "trivial" round ones. Should I delete it?

Comment: Yup. Twas a joke :)

Comment: @belisarius Si no me engaño, usted no me malquería :)

Comment: [Never](http://www.amazon.com/LA-MALQUERIDA-Dolores-del-Rio/dp/B004O4SJ92) :D

Comment: This seems to work: `Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/6ErpY.jpg"]` -- :D  ;P

Comment: @MichaelE2 What you got is a lack of cynicism.

Comment: What I got is a lack of time.  I might get a nice font, convert glyphs to `FilledCurves`, transform, and presto.  Trying to do it *artistically* would take ten times longer.  Maybe I'd get lucky.  You'll probably get some cool answers, though.

Comment: 24-hour clock? http://xkcd.com/now Just overlay the minute and second hands.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A square clock in base 12:

[image]

How to:

```
(*Too lazy,stolen from@blochwave*)
thetaList = Rest@Range[2 Pi, 0, -2 Pi/12] + Pi/2;
coordinateList = 1/4 {Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ thetaList;
i = ImagePad[ImageCrop[Image@ImageData@Graphics[{FontFamily -> "Algerian", FontSize -> 100, 
             Rotate~MapThread~{Text~MapThread~{ToString /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C},
                              coordinateList}, Abs[-Pi/2 + thetaList]}}]], 2, White]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Some Transformation functions. Surely can be shorter, [but the real thing isn't easy](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i2/contents/IntegralEquations/IntegralEquations_3.html) ...

```
f[x_] := IntegerPart@Rescale[Mod[ArcTan[x[[1]], x[[2]]], 2 Pi], {0, 2 Pi}, {0, 8}]
s = (321/2 - 82)/(321/2);
s1 = 1/3;

sc[x_] :=   {s  Cos[ArcTan @@ x], Cos[ArcTan @@ x]}
ss[x_] :=   {s  Sin[ArcTan @@ x], Sin[ArcTan @@ x]}
stan[x_] := {s1 Sin[ArcTan @@ x], Tan[ArcTan @@ x]}
scot[x_] := {s1 Cos[ArcTan @@ x], Cot[ArcTan @@ x]}

h[s1_] := If [Norm@# < s, {0, 0},
    Which[
     1 <= f@# <= 2, {Rescale[#[[1]], sc@#, scot@#],         Rescale[#[[2]], ss@#, {s1, 1}]},
     3 <= f@# <= 4, {Rescale[#[[1]], sc@#, {-s1, -1}],      Rescale[#[[2]], ss@#, stan@# {1, -1}]},
     5 <= f@# <= 6, {Rescale[#[[1]], sc@#, scot@# {1, -1}], Rescale[#[[2]], ss@#, {-s1, -1}]},
     True,          {Rescale[#[[1]], sc@#, {s1, 1}],        Rescale[#[[2]], ss@#, stan@#]}]] &;

sqc = ImagePad[ImageTake[ImageForwardTransformation[i, h[s1], DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
                  4 {1, -1}, 4 {1, -1}], 2]

ImageCompose[sqc, ImageResize[ImagePad[i, 1], 140]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Full code for the working clock:

```
ic= ColorReplace[ImageCompose[sqc,ImageResize[ImagePad[i, 1], 140]],White -> Lighter@Lighter@Orange]
makeHand[col_, fl_, bl_, fw_, bw_, d_] := {col, EdgeForm[Darker@Orange], 
          Polygon[{{-bw, -bl, d}, {bw, -bl, d}, {fw, fl, d}, {0, fl + 8 fw, d}, {-fw, fl, d}}/9]};
hourHand = makeHand[Darker@Darker@Green, 5, 5/3, .1, .3, .1];
minuteHand = makeHand[Darker@Darker@Green, 7, 7/3, .1, .3, .2];
secondHand = makeHand[Red, 7, 7/3, .1/2, .2, .3];
g1 = Graphics3D[{{Texture[ic], 
    Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}, 
            VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
   Rotate[hourHand, Dynamic[Refresh[-30 Mod[AbsoluteTime[]/3600, 60] \[Degree],
                            UpdateInterval -> 60]], {0, 0, 1}], 
   Rotate[minuteHand, Dynamic[Refresh[-6 Mod[AbsoluteTime[]/60, 60] \[Degree],
                            UpdateInterval -> 1]], {0, 0, 1}], 
   Rotate[secondHand,Dynamic[Refresh[-6 Mod[AbsoluteTime[], 60] \[Degree],
                            UpdateInterval -> 1/20]], {0, 0, 1}]}, Boxed -> False, 
   Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

Now you've your watch going. But still there is an interesting problem to solve: How do you capture it to show a running gif at the site. I found a nice (I believe) way to do it:

```
b = {};
t = CreateScheduledTask[AppendTo[b, Rasterize@g1], {2, 30}];
StartScheduledTask[t];
While[MatchQ[ ScheduledTasks[], {ScheduledTaskObject[_, _, _, _, True]}], Pause[1]];
RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]];
Export["c:\\test.gif", b, "DisplayDurations" -> 1]
```

The resulting file is the first gif in the post.

Comment: Your answer is joyfully accepted. Borges would have loved a clock without fingers: "And yet,and yet..." - Borges, Nueva refutación del tiempo, última frase :)

Comment: @eldo Make the following experiment: Take whatever Borges said about time, mirrors, libraries and labyrinths and permute those substantives in the subject of the sentences ...

Comment: "A blasphemous man suggested that all men should juggle letters and symbols until they constructed, by an improbable gift of chance, these canonical books."

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Indeed, this is a base 13 clock (not 12), you are just not using the 0 symbol. 12 in base 12 is 10 (not C).

Answer (score 19):

It's definitely too slow for a real time clock but it doesn't look too bad so I thought i'd share my work.  I simply build a normal clock and distorted it into rectangular shape with `ImageTransformation`.

```
b = ContourPlot[Evaluate[Sum[Sin[RandomReal[9, 2].{x, y}], {5}]], {x, -1,  1},
      {y, -1, 1}, BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Black}, 
      RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 1], 
      Frame -> None, ImageSize -> 600];

clock = Graphics[{Thickness[0.013], Circle[], Thickness[0.003], 
    Table[Line[{0.9 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, 0.95 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}}], {a, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/60}],
    Thickness[0.013], 
    Table[Line[{0.9 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, 0.95 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}}], {a, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/12}],
    Table[
     Rotate[Style[
       Text[IntegerString[i, "Roman"], 
       1.1 {Cos[-i Pi/6 + Pi/2], Sin[-i Pi/6 + Pi/2]}], Bold, Thick, 
       35, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], i*- 30 Degree], {i, 1, 12}],
    Rotate[Polygon[{{-0.03, -5/27}, {0.03, -5/27}, {0.01, 5/9},
       {0, 0.64}, {-0.01, 5/9}}], 40 Degree, {0, 0}],
    Rotate[Polygon[{{-0.03, -7/27}, {0.03, -7/27}, {0.01, 7/9}, 
       {0, 0.86}, {-0.01, 7/9}}], -40 Degree, {0, 0}], RGBColor[1, 0, 0],    
    EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0]], 
    Rotate[Polygon[{{-0.016, -7/27}, {0.016, -7/27}, {0.0055, 8/9},
      {0, 0.93}, {-0.0055, 8/9}}], -150 Degree, {0, 0}],
    Thickness[0.003], White, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.04],
    Thickness[0.005], Black, Circle[{0, 0}, 0.04]}];

res = ImageTransformation[Show[b, clock, PlotRangePadding -> 0.2], 
    {#[[1]]*Sqrt[1 - #[[2]]^2/2], #[[2]]*Sqrt[1 - #[[1]]^2/2]} &, 
    DataRange -> {{-1.0, 1.0}, {-1.0, 1.0}}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Some stuff is stolen from [this](http://blog.wolfram.com/2007/07/09/always-the-right-time-for-mathematica/) terrible article.

Answer (score 19):

**Using ImageTransformation**

```
tf[{x_, y_}] := {(2 x)/(1 + y), (2 y)/(1 + y)};
{" XI  XII    I  ", " II   III  IV ", " V    VI  VII ", " VIII IX   X  "};
im = Graphics[Text[
      Style[#, Bold, 100, FontFamily -> "Times", 
       FontTracking -> "Narrow"]], ImageSize -> {450, 70}] & /@ %;
tr = ImageTransformation[#, tf, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
     Padding -> White] & /@ im;
Graphics[Table[Rotate[{Texture[tr[[i]]],
    r = 1/2; Polygon[{{-r, r}, {r, r}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{.25, 0}, {.75, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
    -π/2 (i - 1), {0, 0}], {i, 4}]]
```

> [image]

**Using FindGeometricTransform, ParametricPlot**

```
pts[t_, r_] := # {t, r t} & /@ {{-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}
tf2[{u_, v_}, t_, r_] := (FindGeometricTransform[#,
       {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}][[2]][{u, v}] &) /@
  MapThread[
   Join, {Partition[pts[t, r], 2, 1, 1], 
    Reverse /@ Partition[pts[2 r, r], 2, 1, 1]}]
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[tf2[{u, v}, 1, 1]], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> ({Opacity[1], Texture[#]} & /@ im)]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

**Image-Manipulate Version**

```
Clear[r]; DynamicModule[{t, r, hour, min, sec, ht, mt, st},
 Manipulate[
  {hour, min, sec} = Take[DateList[], -3];
  ht = π/2 - (hour π)/6 - (min π)/360; 
  mt = π/2 - (min π)/30; st = π/2 - π/30  Floor[sec];
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[tf2[{u, v}, t r, r]],{u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
   PlotStyle -> ({Opacity[.9], Texture[#]} & /@ im),
   AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   ImageSize -> 300, Axes -> False, Frame -> False, Mesh -> None, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None,
   Epilog -> {AbsoluteThickness[5],
     Line[{{0, 0}, .7 t r {Cos[ht], r Sin[ht]}}],
     Gray, Line[{{0, 0}, t r {Cos[mt], r Sin[mt]}}],
     Red, AbsoluteThickness[Large], 
     Line[{{0, 0}, .9 t r {Cos[st], r Sin[st]}}]}],
  {{t, 1.2}, .6, 1.5}, {{r, .7}, .5, 1},
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
 ]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Very very nice - Almost like a Cartier :)

Comment: @eldo the problem with multichar hour marks is the difficulty in getting the right angular position. Hence my "base12" clock :)

Answer (score 8):

Here's my first attempt - no styling (so not very artistic), but it does put the numbers at the right angle.

It makes use of `IntegerString[number, "Roman"]`.

```
hours = 12;
radiusX = 1;
radiusY = 0.7;
thetaList = Rest@Range[2 Pi, 0, -2 Pi/hours] + Pi/2;
coordinateList = {radiusX*Cos@#, radiusY*Sin@#} & /@ thetaList;
Graphics[{
  FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 30, 
  Rotate~MapThread~{Text~
     MapThread~{IntegerString[Range@hours, "Roman"], coordinateList}, 
    Abs[-Pi/2 + thetaList]},
  Black, Thickness[0.008], Arrowheads[Large], 
  Arrow[{{0, 0}, 0.75*coordinateList[[1]]}],
  Black, Thickness[0.008], Arrowheads[Large], 
  Arrow[{{0, 0}, 0.6*coordinateList[[12]]}],
  Transparent, EdgeForm[Directive[Thick]], 
  Rectangle[{-1.2*radiusX, -1.2*radiusY}, {1.2*radiusX, 1.2*radiusY}]
}]
```

Which produces:

[image]

I had a go at using `GeometricTransformation` to distort the text too, but didn't get far...I've certainly not thought this through fully, so hopefully someone might jump in and correct my mistakes! This gives a suitable text-shearing, but doesn't place them in the right position.

```
hours = 12;
radiusX = 1;
radiusY = 0.7;
thetaList = Rest@Range[2 Pi, 0, -2 Pi/hours] + Pi/2;
coordinateList = {radiusX*Cos@#, radiusY*Sin@#} & /@ thetaList;

shearingList = 
  If[Mod[#, Pi/4] != 0, 
     ShearingTransform[-Abs[-Pi/2 - #], {0, 1}, {1, 0}], 
     ShearingTransform[0, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]] & /@ thetaList;

rotatedText = {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 30, 
   Rotate~MapThread~{GeometricTransformation~
      MapThread~{Text~
        MapThread~{IntegerString[Range@hours, "Roman"], 
         coordinateList}, shearingList}, Abs[-Pi/2 + thetaList]}};

Graphics[{rotatedText, Black, Thickness[0.008], Arrowheads[Large], 
  Arrow[{{0.0, 0.0}, 0.75*coordinateList[[1]]}],
  Black, Thickness[0.008], Arrowheads[Large], 
  Arrow[{{0.0, 0.0}, 0.6*coordinateList[[12]]}],
  Transparent, EdgeForm[Directive[Thick]], 
  Rectangle[{-1.2*radiusX, -1.2*radiusY}, {1.2*radiusX, 
    1.2*radiusY}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: so creative =D (+1)

Comment: It's the new smartwatch. The numbers slither by your wrist ;D

Comment: @belisarius for it to be a smartwatch we need it to send [personal data](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bp+120%2F80) to Wolfram.

Answer (score 7):

For a constant angular speed watch, if you want some specific figures being placed at the corners, you have to adjust the aspect ratio of the dial rectangle.

A `Graphics` to begin with:

```
Manipulate[
    {
                    Dashed, GrayLevel[.7], 
                    InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, Through[{Cos, Sin}[π/6 #]]],
                    Dashing[{}], Black, Thick, 
                    InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, Through[{Cos, Sin}[π/12 + π/6 #]]]
                    } & /@ Range[0, 5] //
        Graphics[{#,
                    EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], FaceForm[White],
                    Rectangle[##] & @@ (1/
                                2 {{-1, 1}, (Tan[π/6] + ε) {-1, 
                                                1}})
                    },
                PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, (Tan[π/6] + ε) {-1, 1}},
                Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Thick, FrameTicks -> None] &,
    {{ε, 0}, -0.5, 10}]
```

[image: dial rectangle]

With a proper grid, you can then use the transformation method from other answers to fill in good-looking figures.

Comment: Haven't see you around for a long time! Welcome back!

Comment: @belisarius *I'll be back!* :D

Answer (score 5):

I think that the main problem here is the characteristic deformations of the numbers  due to the square clock.

Here is my attempt to reproduce the shape of the "XI" in the first square clock !

First some initialisation :

```
num = Text[ Style["XI", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 120]];
gnum = Rasterize[num, RasterSize -> 400];
```

then my interactive tool :

```
Manipulate[FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
{{c1, 0}, {c2, 0}, {c3, h}, {c4, h}}, TransformationClass -> "Perspective"] //
 ImageTransformation[gnum, #[[2]], 300, Padding -> padcolor] &,
 {{c1,0.346}, 0., 0.9}, {{c2, 0.882}, 0.50, 1}, {{c3, 0.75}, 0., 1}, {{c4, 0}, 0.0, 1}, 
{{h, 0.875}, -1, 2}, {padcolor, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

You can play with the slider to change the shape.

You just need to modify the initialisation to try with some other number.